# ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker hide time

Tags: php, jquery, forms, zend-framework, datepicker

I'm developing an app with PHP and Zend Framework, i've a form where the user should input a date and i do this field with JQuery and `ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker`.

It's  work fine but my problem is that is shown the calendar for choosing the date and also a list of times to  chose and i want ONLY the date.

This is my code,

**FORM**:

```
$dtstart = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker("datainizio", array("label" => "Data controllo: *"));
        $dtstart->setJQueryParam('dateFormat', 'dd.mm.yy');
        $dtstart->setRequired(true);
        $this->addElement($dtstart);
```

**JAVASRIPT:**

```
$("#datainizio").datetimepicker({
        format:'Y-m-d',
        inline:true,
        lang:'it',
        step: 10
    });
```

Can I solve it?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Add `'showTimepicker': false` to the jquery code:

```
$("#datainizio").datetimepicker({
    format:'Y-m-d',
    'showTimepicker': false,
    inline:true,
    lang:'it',
    step: 10
});
```